# INT values from website HTML with "pure" JavaScript > exract and put into array

Tags: javascript, html, scriptable

I want to modify my [existing Scriptable widget](https://github.com/bjoerrrn/BloodDonationBarometer) for iOS, showing a so called "blood groups barometer", meaning the current status of blood reserves at the German Red Cross and Swiss Red Cross.

There is a private blood provider, called Haema - and I want to add their barometer to the script / widget.

I have found [this website](https://www.haema.de/blutspende/), where the status is given in the source code, in the form of file names of SVG images to the corresponding blood group:

```html
<div class="blood-demand">
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-50-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">A+</div></div>
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-100-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">A-</div></div>
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-75-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">0+</div></div>
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-100-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">0-</div></div>
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-50-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">B+</div></div>
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-100-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">B-</div></div>
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-50-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">AB+</div></div>
  <div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-75-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">AB-</div></div>
</div>
```

Depending on the percent value provided in the file name, I want to create an array which stores that percent value:

```js
...
let result={};
result.a_plus     = <how to get percent value as int?>;
result.b_plus     = <how to get percent value as int?>;
result.ab_plus    = <how to get percent value as int?>;
result.zero_plus  = <how to get percent value as int?>;
result.a_neg      = <how to get percent value as int?>;
result.b_neg      = <how to get percent value as int?>;
result.ab_neg     = <how to get percent value as int?>;
result.zero_neg   = <how to get percent value as int?>;
...
if      (i <=  15){ return ""; }
else if (i <=  25){ return ""; }
else if (i <=  50){ return ""; }
else if (i <=  75){ return ""; }
else if (i <= 100){ return ""; }
...
```

The point is, that Scriptable is not working with jQuery.
But I am able to payload the full HTML with the following:

```js
const url = `https://www.haema.de/blutspende/`;      
let request = new Request(url)
let payload = await request.loadString()
let stack = widget.addStack()
const infoText = stack.addText(payload);
```

Any hint, how I can extract the percent (integer) values from the single blood groups?
Thx in advance.

**Update #1**

It seems that 'document.querySelectorAll' can be an alternative for DOMParser(), as DOMParser() does not work:

```js
const url = 'https://xxx/'
const wv = new WebView() // working within Scriptable
await wv.loadURL(url)

let js = `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.blood-demand div')).map( div => Array.from(div.children).map(div => div.innerText, img => img.src))`;
const data = await wv.evaluateJavaScript(js)
```

Unfortunately, the result currently looks like this:

`[["","A+"],[],["","A-"],[],["","0+"],[],["","0-"],[],["","B+"],[],["","B-"],[],["","AB+"],[],["","AB-"],[]]`

Any hint, how to modify the query to receive something like that (taking the extracted example HTML from above?

`[[50,"A+"],[100,"A-"],[75,"0+"],[100,"0-"],[50,"B+"],[100,"B-"],[50,"AB+"],[75,"AB-"]]`

Comment: Split those URLs at the `-` character, and access the 2nd element of the resulting array?

Comment: Don't know how to iterate through the elements. Something like getElement..? Thx for some coding guidance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

Given you're *able* to get the HTML you snippeted above:

- Create a function `getSymbol(n)` that returns the icons (*stats*) string given a Number `n`
- Create a function `parser()` that returns an Object with the necessary data.
- To get a number (percent) from a string use `.replace(/\D/g, "")` where `\D` stands for *"Not a digit"* - which basically removes anything that is not one. Remember that if your `src` value changes in the future you'll have to modify the JS accordingly.

```js
const getSymbol = (n) => {
  return n <= 15 ? "" :
    n <= 25 ? "" :
    n <= 50 ? "" :
    n <= 75 ? "" :
    "";
};

const parser = (HTMLString) => {

  const DOC = new DOMParser().parseFromString(HTMLString, "text/html");
  const elsItems = DOC.querySelectorAll(".blood-demand--item");
  
  const result = {};
  
  elsItems.forEach(elItem => {
    const txt = elItem.textContent.replace(/[\-+]/, (v) => ({"+": "_plus", "-": "_neg"}[v]));
    const pct = Number(elItem.querySelector("img").src.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    result[txt] = getSymbol(pct);
  });
  
  return result;
};

// Use like:
const HTMLResponse = `<div class="blood-demand"><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-50-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">A+</div></div><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-100-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">A-</div></div><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-15-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">0+</div></div><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-100-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">0-</div></div><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-50-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">B+</div></div><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-25-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">B-</div></div><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-50-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">AB+</div></div><div class="blood-demand--item"><img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/Blutspende/Blutampel/Transfusius-75-prozent-haema.svg" width="162" height="300"><div class="blood-demand--title">AB-</div></div></div>`;
const result = parser(HTMLResponse);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thx. getSymbol function exists. Unfortunately: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: DOMParser -> I assume, this is Scriptable specific and probably not supported.

Comment: Found this one - could it be an option to integrate? (see update #1 above)

Comment: besides the update #1 above, could an extended RegExp be an alternative, RegExp through the already given HTML extract / string and extract a map / array of values (percent + blood group)? sth like `let titleRegExp = new RegExp("<div class=\"caption2 singleline\"><a.*>(.*)</a>"); let titleMatch = html.match(titleRegExp));`